# samba on linux, hosts allow doesn't work correctly

Tags: samba

I hosts allow setting:

```
hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/100
```

So I want every computer within my network to be able to access the server.

Now every IP is good with this setting, but 192.168.1.2 simply doesn't want to connect!

Any ideas why? this is simply illogical... when I disable hosts allow setting all computers can access  so the problem is this line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bitmask after the 192.168.1.0 part seems wrong (never seen 100 before), I guess you pretty much mask everything out.

Try 192.168.1.0/24 instead.

You can also use a [calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=C) for the bitmask if you need other IP-ranges.

Just assuming you might have gotten the part after the slash wrong, it does not say from 0 to 100, it tells you about how many numbers of the given adress are kind of hardcoded and how many are variable.
Check the wikipedia article on [ipv4 subnetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#IPv4_subnetting), if you are interested in how this works.

Comment: Yes, the CIDR Notation you are using is impossible, an ipv4 address is only 32 bits in length. Walter is correct, /24 to /32 would be the only valid range on a 192.168.1.x network. This number depicts the subnet mask of the network portion of the address. Though /32 would make it broadcast but that is outside the scope of this question and answer. +1 to this answer.

Comment: I thought 0/100 meant from 0 to 100 :) learn everyday! thanks. I will also read more to understand what it means.